# Writing a method that swaps every two consecutive strings in an array using loops

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have the following array.

```
{"Cecilia", "Jasmine", "David", "John", "Sylvia", "Bill", "Austin", "Bernardo", "Christopher", "Leticia", "Ronaldo"}
```

And it is supposed to be printed as follows:

```
"Jasmine" "Cecilia" "John" "David" and so on...
```

Following is my code:

```
public static String SwapString(String [] arr) 
{
    String str;
    String str1;
    if(arr.length%2!=0)
    {
        for (int i=1;i<arr.length-1;i+= 2) 
        {
            str = arr[i-1];
            str1 = arr[i+1];
            System.out.println (arr[i]+str1);

        }
    }
    return " ";
}
```

Comment: That's great. What exactly is your question about what you have so far? What does it do and what did you expect it to do instead?

Comment: You are not updating the array, not sure if you are supposed

Comment: It looks like you're swapping the one behind `i`, the one in front of `i` and then incrementing `i` by two. Which would make the one that was in front of `i` the one behind, so then itll get swapped with the one in front, and then once `i+=2` is reached itll become the one behind again etc

Answer (score 4):

It appears you were on the right track, but you should actually *swap* the elements in the array. Also, don't return a `String`. And follow Java naming conventions. Like,

```
public static void swapString(String[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i + 1 < arr.length; i += 2) {
        String t = arr[i + 1];
        arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = t;
    }
}
```

Then call / test it like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = { "Cecilia", "Jasmine", "David", "John", "Sylvia", "Bill", "Austin", 
                                         "Bernardo", "Christopher", "Leticia", "Ronaldo" };
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    swapString(arr);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

I get (as requested)

```
[Cecilia, Jasmine, David, John, Sylvia, Bill, Austin, Bernardo, Christopher, Leticia, Ronaldo]
[Jasmine, Cecilia, John, David, Bill, Sylvia, Bernardo, Austin, Leticia, Christopher, Ronaldo]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to start at 0, and print current index (with space, and no return line) and the following but by swapping them at print, then go up by 2 :

```
String current, next;
for (int i=0 ; i<arr.length-1 ; i+= 2) {
    current = arr[i];
    next = arr[i+1];
    System.out.print(next + " " + current + " ");
}
```

[<kbd>Code Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/MxNj3e)

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
int i,l=s.length;   
for(i=1;i<l;i+=2)
{
    System.out.println(s[i]);
    //i--;
    System.out.println(s[i-1]);
}
if(l%2!=0)//if the array is of odd length,it will include the last element 
   System.out.println(s[l-1]);
}
```